# How to get Total supply of EOS?

Tags: cleos

I'm curios about EOS stat data which can fetch from table using 
**cleos get table eosio.token EOS stat**.

In eos authority(https://eosauthority.com/voting), Total EOS Supply value is different from real table data (I used http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/#api).

Q1. How can I get proper value of EOS Total supply?

Q2. Which is right, cleos result or EOS Authority?

Here are captures for your convenience.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Should be the same, but the web interfaces lags behind due to synchronous updates, and it can also fall behind if eosauthority BP falls behind

```
curl --request POST \
     --url publicapi-mainnet.eosauthority.com/v1/chain/get_currency_stats \
     --data '{"symbol":"EOS","code":"eosio.token"}'
```

returns `~1,004,528,250` for me while front-end shows `~1,004,525,681`, so a `~2,600` difference, probably due to synchronisation problems